# File deletion with delete() method in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a little doubt about following code:

```
try {
    File file = new File("writing");
    file.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(file.delete());
    System.out.println(file.exists());

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    pw.print(324.2342);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    br.close();
} catch(IOException ioE) {
    System.out.println("Indeed");
}
```

Why in this circumstance the method file.delete() apparently says that it works as it returns "true" when executed and it gets also confirmed by the `file.exists()` method which returns "false". However at runtime I do not get any exception like *"IOException the file "writing" does not exist"* or something likewise.

Why does the file keep staying in the heap even though deleted physically? Shouldn't it be automatically garbage collected as soon as the delete method gets called? I know it does not because I saw the output.

Comment: I prefer `catch(IOException ioE){System.out.println("Guess what happened?");`

Comment: Consider to use the new NIO File API with Java SE 7.

Comment: Also consider to use the Automatic Resource Management introduced in Java SE 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `File` represents a abstract path, see the JavaDoc for it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html. It does not represent a file handle in the OS.
The line in your code:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
```

Simply creates a new file. Try deleting the file after calling this...

Comment: I understand that, but when I delete it why it does not get deleted also from the heap? would not it make sense? I know that the GC does not guarantee any GC in any time, however I just think it would be reasonable to have it after a prompted and on purpose file deletion in order to guarantee flow control.

Comment: You delete the file on the OS filesystem - you ask the OS to delete a file at that path. The File object in java only represents the path itself not the file. As your code shows you can reuse the path...

Comment: I see that, just wondered why it does not delete the path as well. It would have made sense. However thanks for your response.

Comment: You are right, if I put file.delete() after PrintWriter it gives me the exception I expected.

Answer (score 2):

`File` object represents a path to a physical file on the file system either exists or not. That's why you have `exists()` (to check if it exists) and `createNewFile()` (to create the file if it is not found).

---

Also note that [`PrintWriter(File file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29) creates a new file if it does not exist.

> **Parameters:**
>
> file - The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file
>   exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file
>   will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

Comment: You are right, if I put file.delete() after PrintWriter it gives me the exception I expected.

Answer (score 1):

The File is handle to real file (that exists or not). You create and then delete the file above, as you say - all good so far.

When you come to the PrintWriter later on it creates the file once more when you use it - it doesnt matter that you deleted it before.

In fact depending on your use case this might be exaclty wht you want - you may want to delete an old log file for example before re-createing and writing to it once more.

Finally, nothing in your code will be eligible for garbage collection until your method exist, and even then the underyling file will continue to exist (if you dont delete it agin) - and any garbage colleciton in this case wouldnt effect the underlying file.  It'll be deleted after the delete invokation and exist again once youre PrintWriter is done with it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't have a link to a particular  file, rather to any file pointer by the file's path. With this line you're creating a new file:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
```